# Java: binarySearch not applicable for ArrayList String?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I am trying to store the WordStream words into an arrayList, sort it and binarySearch to count the number of distinct words.

Why is binarySearch not applicable for ArrayList String and how do I solve for the above?

```
  public static int countUnique1C(WordStream words) {
    // Put code for question 1C here: Count unique words using a sorted array.
    // See assignment PDF for full instructions.

    ArrayList<String> arrayListA = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String i : words) {
      arrayListA.add(i);
    }

    Collections.sort(arrayListA);

    int differenceCount = 0;
    for (String i : arrayListA) {
      if (Arrays.binarySearch(arrayListA, words.nextWord()) < 0) {
        differenceCount++;
      }
    }
    return differenceCount;
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is not an array, it''s a list. Replace `Arrays` with `Collections`

Answer (score 0):

first make a new String array the size of your arraylist and then use `myStringArray = arrayListA.toArray(myStringArray)` and then use the binary search on myStringArray